# Prolog - Using terms to represent and access complex, nested data

Tags: data-structures, prolog, nested

```
my_computer([
    case([
        motherboard([board(plastic),ports(metal),slots(plastic),capacitors(plastic)]),
        power_supply_unit([casing(metal),cables(plastic),connectors(plastic),capacitors(plastic),fan(plastic),transformer(metal)]),
        central_processing_unit([board(plastic),fan(plastic),heatsink(metal)]),
        random_access_memory([board(plastic)]),
        graphics_processing_unit([board(plastic),ports(metal),capacitors(plastic),fan(plastic),heatsink(metal)])
    ]),
    monitor([
        lcd_screen(plastic),inverter(plastic),frame(plastic)
    ]),
    keyboard([
        key(plastic),frame(plastic),cable(plastic)
    ]),
    mouse([
        key(plastic),wheel(plastic),casing(plastic),cable(plastic)
    ])
]).
```

What should I do to in order to run questions like `monitor(X).` or `motherboard(X)` to give one or all layers of (sub)materials (Like `my_computer(X).` would do) ?

Would the code below be more useful for asking such questions? Question about one layer of submaterials is answered easily this way.

```
my_computer([case,monitor,keyboard,mouse]).
    case([motherboard,power_supply_unit,central_processing_unit,random_access_memory,graphics_processing_unit]).
        motherboard([board,ports,slots,capacitors]).
        power_supply_unit([casing,cables,connectors,capacitors,fan,transformer]).
        central_processing_unit([board,fan,heatsink]).
        random_access_memory([board]).
        graphics_processing_unit([board,ports,capacitors,fan,heatsink]).
    monitor([lcd_screen,inverter,frame]).
    keyboard(keys,frame,cable).
    mouse([keys,wheel,casing,cable]).
```

Comment: There must not be a space in front of the opening round bracket and the word before it (several times). So write `mouse(` etc.

Comment: @false now to gives me this X = [case([motherboard([board(plastic), ports(metal), slots(plastic), capacitors(plastic)]), power_supply_unit([casing(metal), cables(plastic), connectors(plastic), capacitors(...)|...]), central_processing_unit([board(plastic), fan(plastic), heatsink(...)]), random_access_memory([board(plastic)]), graphics_processing_unit([board(...)|...])]), monitor([lcd_screen(plastic), inverter(plastic), frame(plastic)]), keyboard([keys(plastic), frame(plastic), cable(plastic)]), mouse([keys(plastic), wheel(plastic), casing(plastic), cable(...)])].

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what you are describing. If you want to access the details, I'd recommend your first take a Prolog book, like Art of Prolog and learn the language first.

Comment: @false Thanks. But what about the three dots? How do I display the whole answer?

Comment: If you're using SWI Prolog, then read [Help: I want the whole answer](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/AllOutput.html)

Comment: So I just have to run `set_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_options,
                   [quoted(true), portray(true)])`. at start. Thanks

Comment: @lurker Would you mind checking my revised question? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This might be a good use case for [pairs](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=pairs),  [association lists](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=assoc), or [records](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=record), depending on how elaborate the data gets.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer to your questions would be:

```
monitor(X) :-
    my_computer([_, monitor(X), _, _]).
```

And similarly for `keyboard` or `mouse`, etc. The `motherboard` would be a layer deeper:

```
motherboard(X) :-
    my_computer([case([motherboard(X), _, _, _, _), _, _, _]).
```

These predicates of course assume a fixed structure. If you wanted it a bit more general, you could do a more elaborate "hunt" for the embedded functors (`monitor`, `motherboard`, etc).

Depending upon your broader application goals, it's not clear to me that this is the best representation of the data. Good enough for now, but context might want to take it in a different direction.

---

Here's another approach, thinking of the data as individual facts which imply a tree relationship. Basically just `has` relationships. Separate the "material" facts as `material(Item, Type)`:

```
item(my_computer, case).
item(my_computer, monitor).
item(my_computer, keyboard).
item(my_computer, mouse).

item(case, motherboard).
item(case, power_supply_unit).
item(case, central_processing_unit).
item(case, random_access_memory).
item(case, graphics_processing_unit).

item(motherboard, board).
item(motherboard, ports).
item(motherboard, slots).
item(motherboard, capacitors).

item(power_supply_unit, casing).
item(power_supply_unit, cable).
item(power_supply_unit, connectors).
item(power_supply_unit, capacitors).
item(power_supply_unit, fan).
item(power_supply_unit, transformer).

item(central_processing_unit, board).
item(central_processing_unit, fan).
item(central_processing_unit, heatsink).

item(random_access_memory, board).

item(graphics_processing_unit, board).
item(graphics_processing_unit, ports).
item(graphics_processing_unit, capacitors).
item(graphics_processing_unit, fan).
item(graphics_processing_unit, heatsink).

item(monitor, lcd_screen).
item(monitor, inverter).
item(monitor, frame).

item(keyboard, key).
item(keyboard, frame).
item(keyboard, cable).

item(mouse, key).
item(mouse, wheel).
item(mouse, casing).
item(mouse, cable).

material(board, plastic).
material(slots, plastic).
material(capacitors, plastic).
material(ports, metal).
material(casing, metal).
material(cable, plastic).
material(connectors, plastic).
material(fan, plastic).
material(heatsink, metal).
material(lcd_screen, plastic).
material(inverter, plastic).
material(frame, plastic).
material(key, plastic).
material(cable, plastic).
```

Then you can define a predicate to generate the tree for whatever level you wish. Here's an example that does it in the form of terms (not lists):

```
structure(Item, Structure) :-
    (   item(Item, _)
    ->  findall(T, (item(Item, R), structure(R, T)), Rs),
        Structure =.. [Item |Rs]
    ;   Structure = Item
    ).
```

So then:

```
:- structure(case, S).
S = case(motherboard(board,ports,slots,capacitors),
         power_supply_unit(casing,cable,connectors,capacitors,fan,transformer),
         central_processing_unit(board,fan,heatsink),
         random_access_memory(board),
         graphics_processing_unit(board,ports,capacitors,fan,heatsink)
        )
```

This could easily be changed to provide results in a list form instead. For example, here's a predicate that takes the above facts and gives the form you originally presented in your question:

```
structure(Item, Tree) :-
    (   item(Item, _)
    ->  findall(T, (item(Item, R), structure(R, T)), Rs),
        Tree =.. [Item, Rs]
    ;   material(Item, Material),
        Tree =.. [Item, Material]
    ).
```

And the `item` becomes a trivial result for a `where_used(Item, Parent)` predicate:

```
where_used(Item, Parent) :-
    item(Parent, Item).
```

Again, it all depends upon how you want to use and manage the data.

Comment: I love seeing how the possibilities proliferate! You started with a super straightforward, entirely adequate approach that solved the problem in one step. I proposed a slightly more general approach.  Then your comment got me thinking a little more deeply about my approach. By the time I was done adding my *greater* generalization, aimed at diving into the single, compound data-object, you had come up with this *lovely* database-oriented take! It seems to me that both approaches have distinct advantages and disadvantages, and together they exhibit the beautiful flexibility of Prolog :)

Comment: (fwiw, I didn't mean "greater" in the sense of "greater than your approach" but greater than what I had first proposed using `member/2` up).

Comment: @aBathologist no worries. I didn't take it negatively. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

For fun, I cobbled together a pair of rules that generalize arbitrary depth access to structures of the form `name([attr_1([attr_1_1,...attr_1_n([...])]), ..., attr_N([...]))`; i.e., to data that is stored as a fact that has the same general form as your `my_computer/1`. You can use it, if you like. In any case, it's a nice little demonstration of Prolog's potent recipe of higher-order predicates + explicit evaluation + homoiconicity:

```
attribute(Thing, Path) :-
    call(Thing, Attributes),
    path_through_attributes(Path, Attributes).

path_through_attributes(Path, Attributes) :-
    ( Path = (Func -> NextPath), atom(Func)
    ->
        Attr =.. [Func, NextAttributes],
        member(Attr, Attributes),
        path_through_attributes(NextPath, NextAttributes)
    ;
        compound(Path),
        member(Path, Attributes)
    ).
```

Supposing we have a fact like `my_computer/1` (just as it appears in the first part of your question), the the predicate `attribute/2` can be used to access any of its attributes, nested at any depth, like so:

```
?- attribute(my_computer, case(X)).
X = [motherboard([board(plastic), ports(metal), slots(plastic), capacitors(plastic)]), power_supply_unit([casing(metal), cables(plastic), connectors(plastic), capacitors(plastic), fan(plastic), transformer(...)]), central_processing_unit([board(plastic), fan(plastic), heatsink(metal)]), random_access_memory([board(plastic)]), graphics_processing_unit([board(plastic), ports(metal), capacitors(...)|...])] 

?- attribute(my_computer, case -> power_supply_unit(X)).
X = [casing(metal), cables(plastic), connectors(plastic), capacitors(plastic), fan(plastic), transformer(metal)] 

?- attribute(my_computer, case -> power_supply_unit -> transformer(X)).
X = metal
```

I chose the `->/2` operator for the accessor-path simply because it has a convenient associativity (i.e., right: `(a -> (b -> c))`) and it is sort of suggestive of "reaching into a series of nested terms". But it's probably not a great choice. If I were going to use this frequently, I'd come up with a good operator for the purpose and declare it with `op/3`.

---

Since all the terms in `my_computer/1` are in a list, you could make a general access predicate using member:

```
computer_attribute(Attr) :-
    my_computer(Attributes),
    member(Attr, Attributes).
```

It can be used like so:

```
?- computer_attribute(monitor(X)).
X = [lcd_screen(plastic), inverter(plastic), frame(plastic)]
```

Of course, because `monitor` is nested in `case`, you'll need to have a more specific approach to access the former.

Depending on how elaborate the data gets, this might be a good use case for [pairs](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=pairs),  [association lists](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=assoc), or [records](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=record). (There is also the new SWI Prolog extension providing the [`dict`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=dicts) compound, but I don't recommend it. I have found them to be more trouble then they are worth. But that might just be a shortcoming on my side.)

The indentation of your second block of code makes it look like there is a hierarchical relationship between the `my_computer/1` fact and the others, but that is an illusion. Proper indentation makes clear that each is simply stated as an independent fact:

```
my_computer([case,monitor,keyboard,mouse]).
case([motherboard,power_supply_unit,central_processing_unit,random_access_memory,graphics_processing_unit]).
motherboard([board,ports,slots,capacitors]).
power_supply_unit([casing,cables,connectors,capacitors,fan,transformer]).
central_processing_unit([board,fan,heatsink]).
random_access_memory([board]).
graphics_processing_unit([board,ports,capacitors,fan,heatsink]).
monitor([lcd_screen,inverter,frame]).
keyboard(keys,frame,cable).
mouse([keys,wheel,casing,cable]).
```

As a result, this representation will only work if you only have one computer with the relevant parts in the given namespace. Otherwise, if you have a second computer, you won't be able to tell which call to `mouse(X)` is supposed to be associated with which computer. However, you could give each computer a name and then define the different attributes as relations between the computers name and a list of terms. Then your representation would like so:

```
computer(mine).
case(mine, [motherboard,power_supply_unit,central_processing_unit,random_access_memory,graphics_processing_unit]).
....
```

This code can be queried like so:

```
?- computer(Name), motherboard(Name, Specs).
Name = mine,
Specs = [board, ports, slots, capacitors].
```

(Once you have a firm grasp of Prolog, you might want to investigate [Logtalk](http://logtalk.org/), which is an OOP extension for Prolog. I have never used it, but it sound fun.)

Comment: Using `member` is definitely the way to go since he's organized with lists (+1).  That's where I was headed next, but you beat me to it. :)

Comment: Thanks for that, and not subtracting points for my persistent misspelling of query as quarry :P. I (+1)ed you for the concision and simple effectiveness of your original answer. But I see you've also updated yours with a more elaborate approach!

Answer (score 1):

You can also define a bill of materials (BOM) using definite clause grammar rules (DCGs). For example:

```
my_computer -->
    case, monitor, keyboard, mouse.

case -->
    motherboard, power_supply_unit, central_processing_unit,
    random_access_memory, graphics_processing_unit.

motherboard -->
    [board], [ports], [slots], [capacitors].

power_supply_unit -->
    [casing], [cables], [connectors], [capacitors], [fan], [transformer].

central_processing_unit -->
    [board], [fan], [heatsink].

random_access_memory -->
    [board].

graphics_processing_unit -->
    [board], [ports], [capacitors], [fan], [heatsink].

monitor -->
    [lcd_screen], [inverter], [frame].

keyboard -->
    [keys], [frame], [cable].

mouse -->
    [keys], [wheel], [casing], [cable].
```

Parts that have components, e.g. `monitor`, are represented as non-terminals. Parts that are not made of other parts, e.g. `keys`, are represented as terminals (i.e. between square brackets). The standard `phrase/2` predicate can be used to get the bill of materials for a specific part. For example:

```
| ?- phrase(monitor, Parts).

Parts = [lcd_screen,inverter,frame]
yes

| ?- phrase(case, Parts).

Parts = [board,ports,slots,capacitors,casing,cables,connectors,capacitors,fan,transformer,board,fan,heatsink,board,board,ports,capacitors,fan,heatsink]
yes
```

If you need to represent detailed information about a specific part, e.g. that a fan have three different modes, which one with its own RPMs, you can interpret the part name (which is an atom) as either a Prolog module or a Logtalk object identifier. The module or object can then nicely hold the details about the part.